# How to extract base path from DataFrame column of path strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, os.path

There are several questions about string manipulation, but I can't find an answer which allows me to do the following—I thought it should have been simple...

I have a DataFrame which includes a column containing a filename and path

The following produces a representative example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'root': {'1': 'C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3\\folder4\\filename.csv'}
})
```

```
                                              root
1  C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\filename.csv
```

I want to end up with just the 'filename' part of the string. There is a large number of rows and the path is not constant, so I can't use `str.replace`

I can strip out the rightmost '.csv' part like this:

```
df['root'] = df['root'].str.rstrip('.csv')
```

```
                                          root
1  C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\filename
```

But I cannot make any of the methods I have read about work to remove the path part in the left side of the string.

How can I return just the 'filename' part of this path (string), given that the preceding elements of the path can change from record to record?

Comment: Depending on the form of your filenames, DSM's answer is the more robust but if the presumptions I've made are true I would expect the `str` based methods to be faster as they are vectorised

Comment: Thanks, EdChum, so quick to answer and really helpful. Very difficult to know which answer to select, but I think the robustness you acknowledge in DSM's answer, plus the extra info concerning rstrip tips the scales... Appreciate the help nonetheless.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the utilities in [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html) to make this easier, namely `splitext` and `basename`:

```
>>> import os
>>> df["root"].apply(lambda x: os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0])
0    filename
Name: root, dtype: object
```

---

PS: [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) doesn't work the way you think it does-- it removes those *characters*, not that substring.  For example:

```
>>> "a11_vsc.csv".rstrip(".csv")
'a11_'
```

Comment: This is working and does exactly what I asked. Thanks very much for the help and also for the extra info ref rstrip

Answer (score 3):

For recent Python, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is recommended. The basename can be obtained by applying `.stem` as follows. In general, DataFrames often have multiple rows, so the examples below also use pandas `.apply`.

```python
from pathlib import Path 

df['root'].apply(lambda x: Path(x).stem)
# Out[1]:
# 1    filename
# Name: root, dtype: object
```

If you want to include the extension, you can get it by applying `.name`.

```python
df['root'].apply(lambda x: Path(x).name)
# Out[2]:
# 1    filename.csv
# Name: root, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Presuming there is always at least a single depth in the path, we can split on the slashes, take the last element and then call rstrip on it:

```
In [9]:

df.root.str.split('\\').str[-1].str.rstrip('.csv')
Out[9]:
1    filename
Name: root, dtype: object
```

**EDIT** in light of what DSM has pointed out about rstrip, you could call split twice:

```
In [11]:

df.root.str.split('\\').str[-1].str.split('.').str[0]
Out[11]:
1    filename
Name: root, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing whatsoever pandas-specific about this, it is basic path handling with [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

Second, [Windows/DOS has been accepting / as a path separator for at least 10-15 years now](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23123-when-did-windows-start-accepting-forward-slash-path-separator). So you can and should write `mypath = 'C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/filename.csv'`
As you noticed, using backslash makes your string-handling life difficult because it has to be escaped, and results in nastier code. Defining `os.sep = r'\\'` doesn't seem to work.

```
import os
os.path.basename(r'C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/filename.csv')
'filename.csv'
```

Now if you *really* want to insist on writing OS-specific code in your Python (though there's no reason at all to do this), you can use the little-known platform-specficic versions of os.path:

```
import ntpath  # Windows/DOS-specific versions of os.path
ntpath.basename(r'C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\filename.csv')
'filename.csv'
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of os.path until the previous answer -- I thought it was a pandas issue because I am dealing with a pandas DataFrame. Neither was I aware that the forward slash was acceptable as a separator -- just never had cause to consider it. I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding the useage of your suggestion: 'os.path.basename(r'C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/filename.csv'), but the actual paths in my data vary, and are the result of reading in a large number of csv files -- I cannot state the path. I'm not sure if that's what you meant. Thanks anyway for the useful info.
'